# Add custom URLs to WordPress's XML sitemap

Tags: hooks, urls, query-string, sitemap

My WordPress site also incorporates some external non-WP content that is dynamically pulled into the page via shortcode. The content shown depends on a query string parameter. So from WP's point of view, `index` is just a single page containing a shortcode; but in reality, when you visit `index?x=1`, `index?x=2`, `index?x=3`, etc. you get different page content depending on the `x` value. (It's a primary key ID into a large external database.)

This works fine, and avoids creating thousands of separate pages in WP, though I do have to filter `get_canonical_url` to ensure that the canonical URL retains the query string with the `x` value (which would otherwise be stripped out by WP).

Now I want to include all of these pages in WP's auto-generated sitemap (`/wp-sitemap.xml`), which, again, currently only lists the single bare URL with no `x` value. I need the sitemap to include `index?x=1`, `index?x=2`, `index?x=3`, etc. to cover every extant ID value.

I can easily write PHP code to generate a list of these URLs, but how do I hook into the sitemap generation process to add them to the default list produced by WP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sitemap Provider

It's possible to create a so called custom **sitemap provider** and register it with [wp_register_sitemap_provider()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_sitemap_provider/).

It's helpful to look at the core setup, e.g. for the [`WP_Sitemaps_Posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_sitemaps_posts/) provider and also the [dev notes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/22/new-xml-sitemaps-functionality-in-wordpress-5-5/).

### Basic Example - Sitemap with custom URLs

Here's a very basic example that adds the **wpse** provider that extends [`WP_Sitemaps_Provider`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Sitemaps_Provider/), through an anonymous class:

```
add_action ( 'init', function () {  
    wp_register_sitemap_provider( 
        'wpse', 
        new class extends \WP_Sitemaps_Provider {
            public function __construct() {
                $this->name = 'wpse'; // public-facing name in URLs says parent class.
            }
            public function get_url_list( $page_num, $post_type = '' ) {
                return array(
                    array(
                        'loc' => add_query_arg( 'x', 1, home_url() ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'loc' => add_query_arg( 'x', 2, home_url() ),
                    ),
                );
            }
            public function get_max_num_pages( $subtype = '' ) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    );
} );
```

It will generate `wp-sitemap-wpse-{PAGE NUMBER <= get_max_num_pages()}.xml` or  `wp-sitemap-wpse-1.xml`:

[image]

that contains these two custom urls:

[image]

### External DB

For an external DB you can adjust the `get_max_num_pages()` and  `get_url_list()` methods above, with the help of e.g.:

- overall number of `x` values from the external DB
- paginated chunk of `x` values from the external DB
- [`wp_sitemaps_get_max_urls()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_sitemaps_get_max_urls/) that's 2000 by default
- current page number `$page_num`

ps: looking around there is a great [article](https://wp-kama.com/handbook/sitemap/create-provider) on wp-kama that will probably help a lot regarding the external DB.